# how to remove margin in drop down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ionic-framework

could you please tell me how to remove margin from drop down as shown in image . I need to display
dropdown down as shown in image .But there is some margin coming from some where .How to make dropdown same as shown in image

here is my code

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BoNwqa

```
/* Styles here */
.dropdown_border{
  border: 1px solid #e4e5e7;
  height: 35px;
  text-align:center;
  color:blue;
}
.dropdown_padding {
  padding: 2em 3.5em 0em 3.5em;
}
.dropdown_image_class {
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  margin-top: -6px;
  border: 1px solid #e4e5e7;
  float: right;

}
```

Comment: Its the padding on your div with class `col dropdown_border` and its setting `padding` all around at `5px`.  You will need to override ionic's `col` style,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following CSS property:

```
.dropdown_border {
    padding: 5px 0 !important;
}
```

**EDIT**

As Praveen suggested, Use this instead:

```
.col.dropdown_border {
    padding: 5px 0;
}
```

Comment: Using `!important` unnecessarily is not good. Please use specificity.

Answer (score 1):

The `.col` has a padding of `5px`. Instead of targetting all the `.col`, give this:

```
.col.dropdown_border {
  padding: 5px 0;
}
```

So that it affects only the `.dropdown_border` class. This way, the `.col` with the class `.dropdown_border` has padding both at top and bottom and not on the sides.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

```
.col.dropdown_border {
    padding: 5px 0;
    border-right: 0px;
}
```

By the way, the dropdown image already got border left and right.